# Basic authentication using Fetch API in JS

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

I'm working on a script featured in an HTML document to display a map of the Boston area using leaftlet, and I'd like to get a list of locations to put on the map from this website. I'm using `fetch` to do this, and so far the code looks like this.

const KEY = 'APIKEY';

const USERNAME = KEY;

const PWD = "";

const URI = 'https://api.quant-aq.com/device-api/v1/account';

const ENCODED_KEY = 'base64encodedAPIKEY'

```
                    async function getData(link) {
                        const response = await fetch("https://api.quant-aq.com/device-api/v1/account", {
                            method: "GET",
                            headers: {
                                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PWD),
                                // 'X-API-KEY' : KEY,
                                // "X-Auth-Token": KEY,
                                'Host': 'quant-aq.com',
                                'Accept': 'application/json',
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            },
                            mode: "no-cors"
                        })
                        console.log(response.json())
                        
                            
                    }

                    getData(URI);
```

I should mention that I'm pretty new to JS (and querying APIs hehe), so I'm not entirely familiar with what HTTPS errors typically imply in the code. I've tried having all of the headers in the fetch call uncommented with no success; I continually get an error 401.

The documentation is located here: https://docs.quant-aq.com/api#ac146fbf650b4f98addf9c6b1705d982

I should also mention that I managed to access their API once using the HTTPie bash versions of GET calls, but am not able to replicate those results in JS. I believe the method I used to call it successfully was with `username:password` rather than `API_KEY`.

Possible questions:

Do you need to have a password? No, a password shouldn't be necessary if I have generated the API key. Their docs also use the key as a username, so that shouldn't be the flaw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> mode: "no-cors"
> ```

Setting the mode to `"no-cors"` causes any attempt to do something that requires CORS permission to silently fail (instead of throwing an exception).

Setting `Authorization` and `Content-Type` headers (although setting a `Content-Type` on a GET request, which can't have content in the first place, doesn't make sense) requires CORS permission.

---

Given that the request requires an API key, and that to use it client-side you would have to distribute your API key to all your users, there is a high probability that the service is not designed to be access directly by web browsers (so you should use server-side code instead).

Comment: Looks like @Quentin is correct; the best way of doing this is probably to use some backend code to access the API and feed that data into the webapp for whatever purposes it is needed for. I've also learned that `mode: "no-cors"` is not only counter-intuitive, but you will almost never want to do it. Thanks!